# Read Excel lines into Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to import the data lines saved in an Excel CSV. How can I save each line's data as a list?

The Excel file has the following type of data:

```
Name   B  C   D
ItemID 3  3   4
Height 5  5   7
Length 6  5   8
```

I want to save [B,C,D] in a list named `Name`, and [3,3,4] as a list named `ItemID`. I tried to used the following code, but it always returns the last line of the file.

```
f = open('part.csv', 'r')
csv_f=csv.reader(f,delimiiter=',')
for row in csv_f:
    name.append(row[1])
    numid.append(row[2])
    height.append(row[3])
    length.append(row[4])
```

Comment: What are actual contents of part.csv?

Comment: Note, Python starts from 0 when accessing lists, so I suggest you try `name.append(row[0])` for the first column. Also `delimiiter` is meant to be `delimiter` although the default is already `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend to consider using **[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)** the python data analysis library.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_df = pd.read_csv('part.csv')
df_T = csv_df.T

print df_T['ItemID'].tolist()
print df_T.index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand that a row has all the columns of that row, e.g. the first time through the loop `row = ['Name', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.
So use a dictionary, with the key as the first column and the rest as the value:

```
data = {}
with open('part.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_f=csv.reader(f,delimiiter=',')
    for row in csv_f:
        data[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Data:

```
{'Height': ['5', '5', '7'],
 'ItemID': ['3', '3', '4'],
 'Length': ['6', '5', '8'],
 'Name': ['B', 'C', 'D']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with open('testdata.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        name.append(row['fieldname'])
```

Comment: This would throw a `KeyError`, `1` is not a valid key for the dictionary in `row`.  `row = {'Name': 'ItemID', 'B': '3', 'C': '3', 'D': '4'}`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is work with a dataframe. Try using the pandas library as it simplifies a lot of the operations.