# How can I check values of an excel sheet using Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv, xlsx

I have an Excel sheet, with data of stock prices and I want to build a code where I check if the guess is correct or not. So I need to compare my python value to the value on the Excel sheet.

I have tried using `repl.it` in a `.csv` file, but it was not compatible and I was not able to check my values. I have also tried using a `.xlsx` file on `repl.it`, but I still could not access the values.

Is there any way I can compare the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Excel lines into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837274/read-excel-lines-into-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel('file_name.xslx')

for row in table.values.tolist():
  first_value_in_row = row[0]
  second_value_in_row = row[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Emad, but I am not sure why this is not working for me. Could this be because of anaconda and pip not being installed?

Comment: Yes, try installing anaconda, or you can run this a python shell directly